# javascript in html inserted on ajax request runs once more with each ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the dialog widget from jquery.
The content for the dialog (`id='juiDialog'`) is generated by ajax request.
The content contains html code (`<form id='formId'...>.. </from>`) and javascript on each request.
Javascript code contains the ajax request function

```
jQuery(function($) {
    jQuery('#juiDialog').delegate('#formId','submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        jQuery.ajax({
            global : false,
            async : false,
            cache : false,
            type : 'POST',
            url : jQuery(this).attr('action'),
            data:jQuery(this).serialize()
        })
        .done(function(){
            var tr=$('#data-grid').find('#updateTr');
            $(tr).css('color','red');
            $('#juiDialog').dialog('close');
            $('#juiDialog').empty();

            alert('Data Saved');
        });
    });
});
```

After each ajax complete function I remove the content form the dialog using  `$('#juiDialog').empty();`

This dialog can be called multiple times in the same page for different items.

The problem is that the script runs each time once more so: called 1 time runs 1 time; called the second time runs 2 times (the alert message is showed twice)

When I put the ajax function into the main page not jquery dialog , the problem stops!!!

I need some help in order to make the script run only once with each ajax request but when the ajax function is retrived into the dialog  `<div>` body.

I think that the javascript code is not removed from the DOM on $('#juiDialog').empty() so it is like I am inserting it each time once more.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? I can see `delegate` there

Comment: jquery Version v1.10.2

Comment: I also used jQuery('#juiDialog').on('submit','#formId',function(e){} function and I get the same result.  I think that the javascript code is not removed from the DOM so it is like I am inserting it each time once more.

Comment: try `$('#formId').remove()`. Since there's no jsfiddle you're gonna have to do the debugging ;)

Comment: @dcodesmith Not working